# Why is my build.sbt looking for version 2.11 of hadoop-streaming?

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, sbt

Im doing a pluralsight course on Apache Spark and at one point they ask us to setup a dependency on Hadoop-streaming. I've added it to my `build.sbt` file, but the results I'm getting are unexpected:

## Build.sbt

```
name := "SparkPlayground"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.0.0" % "provided"
libraryDependencies += "com.github.scala-incubator.io" %% "scala-io-core" % "0.4.3"
libraryDependencies += "com.github.scala-incubator.io" %% "scala-io-file" % "0.4.3"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hadoop" %% "hadoop-streaming" % "2.7.0"
```

## Error message

```
SBT 'SparkPlayground' project refresh failed
    Error:Error:Error while importing SBT project:<br/>...<br/><pre>[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#task-system;0.13.8 ...

[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#tasks;0.13.8 ...

[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#tracking;0.13.8 ...

[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#cache;0.13.8 ...

[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#testing;0.13.8 ...

[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#test-agent;0.13.8 ...

[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#test-interface;1.0 ...

[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#main-settings;0.13.8 ...

[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#apply-macro;0.13.8 ...

[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#command;0.13.8 ...

[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#logic;0.13.8 ...

[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#precompiled-2_8_2;0.13.8 ...

[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#precompiled-2_9_2;0.13.8 ...

[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#precompiled-2_9_3;0.13.8 ...

[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run 'last *:update' for the full output.

[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run 'last *:ssExtractDependencies' for the full output.

[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-streaming_2.11;2.6.0: not found

[error] (*:ssExtractDependencies) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-streaming_2.11;2.6.0: not found

[error] Total time: 13 s, completed Sep 5, 2016 2:05:47 AM
```

From the error message it looks like sbt is looking for hadoop-streaming_2.11 for some reason, but I have no idea where this 2.11 comes from. I'm pretty new to Scala and sbt so I'm guessing I made some dumb typo somewhere

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"If you use groupID %% artifactID % revision rather than groupID % artifactID % revision (the difference is the double %% after the groupID), sbt will add your project’s Scala version to the artifact name."

From [SBT manual](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Library-Dependencies.html).

So you should just use % here.

Comment: So howcome this doesn't break my other dependencies? Do they all really have a scala version appended? That seems weird.

Comment: You can visit http://mvnrepository.com/, and will find your other dependencies in form of xx_2.10.

Comment: Hadoop-streaming is a java library and doesn't depend on scala. Scala libraries however need to be compiled for the scala version that you're using (the 2.11 part of 2.11.8)